# SQL - How to make a Ranking - with Sum and Order?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

My table:

```
USERID ------ SCORE
1999 --------  100
1999 --------  230
2000 --------  210
```

I have many `USERID` and I need to `GROUP BY USERID` to **SUM** all scores of each `USERID` - and make the final **Ranking**.

**I need this:**

```
USERID ----- SCORE ---- USERRANK
 1999 ------ 330 ------    1
 2000 ------ 210 ------    2
```

WITH THIS:

```
   SELECT USERID, SUM(SCORE), (@rownum := @rownum + 1) UserRank 
   FROM RESPOSTAS GROUP BY USERID, (SELECT @rownum := 0)  
   ORDER BY SUM(SCORE) DESC
```

**I Have:**

```
USERID ----- SCORE ---- USERRANK
 1999 ------ 330 ------    1
 2000 ------ 210 ------    1
```

ALL UserID has the same UserRank..

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `(SELECT @rownum := 0)` in FROM clause and wrap the query inside the outer query, e.g.:

```
 SELECT user.userid, user.rank, (@rownum := @rownum + 1) as rank
 from (
  SELECT USERID, SUM(rank) as rank
  FROM user GROUP BY USERID 
  ORDER BY SUM(rank) DESC
  ) user, (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
```

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2d2b6d/1/0).

Comment: hi @Darshan-Mehta! for some reason the Rank is wrong. (like demo posted by @Giorgos-Betsos. I have the same problem here..

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos thanks for the input. I have modified the query.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use variables in an *outer query*, like:

```
   SELECT USERID, sum_score, 
          @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS UserRank 
   FROM (
     SELECT USERID, SUM(SCORE) AS sum_score
     FROM RESPOSTAS 
     GROUP BY USERID ) AS t
   CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0)  AS v
   ORDER BY sum_score DESC
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bb0c03/1)

Comment: Hi @Giorgos-Betsos! First of all, tks for your time and help!! Works great!! Now I'm trying to get the USERRANK for an especific UserID, but when I put the Where USERID = '1999' between Cross Join and Order BY, doesn Works.. do you know why? tks a lot!!

Comment: @DANIEL You need to use yet another outer query. Put the `WHERE` for the `userid` in this outer query.